# Error during filtering and counting of words in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I want to define 5 words and want to filter my dataset based on that 17 words, and count the number of occurrences. 
Suppose,

```
words = ['dog', 'cat','tiger','lion','cheetah']
```

I have a text file which contains sentences ranging more than 2000 lines. I want to search my text file, and return the number of occurrences.

I have searched the internet and found some code, like,

```
val filePath = sc.text_file("/user/cloudera/input/Hin*/datafile.txt")
val crimecounts =
  filePath.
    flatMap(line=>line.split(" ")).
    filter(w => (w =="dog") || (w == "lion")).
    map(word=>(word, 1)).
    reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

This code returns wrong count for "lion". And surprisingly only the count of "lion" is returned. I have checked for correctness of count value using Python code separately. How should the code be corrected so as to return correct count of all 5 words.
Subset of data is as follows,

> It was a hot summer day. A lion and a boar reach a small water body for a drink. Lion and boar begin arguing and fighting about who should drink first. After a while, they are tired and stop for breath, when they notice vultures above. Soon they realize that the vultures are waiting for one or both of them to fall, to feast on them. The lion and the boar then decide that it was best to make up and be friends than fight and become food for vultures. Lion and boar drink the water together and go their ways after.

I am a newbie to Spark. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a small subset of your data? What is the count that you are getting using this code? Also, are you using Python or Scala?

Comment: I am using spark-shell. I am good at Python so I have built a code to test correctness, by `file.read().lower(), and use count() function` Python is no where connected with this code. I have added subset of data by editing it. I am getting Lion count as 2, whereas the small subset of data itself has lion count of 4.

Comment: You have tagged it as pyspark but have used code of scala and pyspark both. please verify

Comment: Cannot see any Python code - why exactly is this tagged as `pyspark`?

Comment: @desertnaut I am newbie to Spark, so I don't know which tag would be appropriate

Comment: @desertnaut I having encoding problems. Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so many errors in your code. The ***array creation part* seems to be in *pyspark* but the rest of the codes look to be in *scala***. And **there is no *text_file* api for *sparkContext* instance**.

**solution for *pyspark* :**

```
words = ['dog', 'cat','tiger','lion','cheetah']

filePath = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/input/Hin*/datafile.txt")
from operator import add
crimecounts = filePath.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).filter(lambda w: w.lower() in words).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(add)
```

**solution for *scala*:**

```
val words = Array("dog","cat","tiger","lion","cheetah")

val filePath = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/input/Hin*/datafile.txt")
val crimecounts = filePath.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).filter(w => words.contains(w.toLowerCase)).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have 2 more doubts. Please don't hesitate to answer. Suppose, if there are another 59 such files, and I want combined count of every word from all files, how should I do that? Another question is, when I am reading the data from file, how to make it case insensitive, and run the file? From your commands, no error is being raised, thanks to you. But an empty RDD is being produced. I have cross checked for presence of data in HDFS.

Comment: I am using Quickstart VM of Cloudera distribution, so I guess it would already be set.

Comment: When I trying to print files in PySpark, all words are prefixed with "\xa0", which I guess it has something to do with encoding. Is that causing any problem?

Comment: Answering your questions: 1) you just have to give the directory path and all the files inside it would be read. 2) you can change all the words to lower cases or use igoreCase(). 3) something is wrong with the hadoop configuration and linking that to spark. 4) there might be some simbols in the text file.