# Difficulty with encoding while reading data in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In connection with my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839791/error-during-filtering-and-counting-of-words-in-spark), when I give the command,

```
filePath = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/input/Hin*/datafile.txt")
filePath.collect()
```

some part of the data has '\xa0' prefixed to every word, and other part of the data doesn't have that special character. I am attaching 2 pictures, one with '\xa0', and another without '\xa0'. [image: With '\xa0'] [image: Without '\xa0'] The content shown in 2 pictures belong to same file. Only some part of the data from same file is read that way by Spark. I have checked the original data file present in HDFS, and it was problem free.

I feel that it has something to do with encoding. I tried all methods like using `replace`option in flatMap like `flatMap(lambda line: line.replace(u'\xa0', ' ').split(" "))`, `flatMap(lambda line: line.replace(u'\xa0', u' ').split(" "))`, but none worked for me. This question might sound dump, but I am newbie in using Apache Spark, and I require some assistance to overcome this problem.

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the encoding of your file. When you use `sc.textFile`, spark expects an UTF-8 encoded file. 
One of the solution is to acquire your file with `sc.binaryFiles` and then apply the expected encoding.

`sc.binaryFile` create a key/value rdd where key is the path to file and value is the content as a byte.
If you need to keep only the text and apply an decoding function, :

```
filePath = sc.binaryFile("/user/cloudera/input/Hin*/datafile.txt")
filePath.map(lambda x :x[1].decode('utf-8')) #or another encoding depending on your file
```

Comment: Like `filePath = sc.binaryFiles("/user/cloudera/Hin*/datafile.txt")`? Then where should I apply the encoding method?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Where should I add your map function? `filePath.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).filter(lambda w: w.lower() in words).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(add)` I want to search for predefined words and count their number of occurrences. This is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839791/error-during-filtering-and-counting-of-words-in-spark) of my earlier question.

Comment: @JohnDeer you start with the decode function, as I wrote it. Then you apply your count.

Comment: Like, first 2 lines will be your code, followed by `filePath.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).filter(lambda w: w.lower() in words).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(add)` will be 3rd line and `collect()` in the end, right?

Comment: @JohnDeer Yes. But be sure to know your encoding format. `utf-8` won't work probably. Do you know how to check the encoding of your file ?

Comment: No! I don't know. How should I check? @Steven

Comment: if you can download it on local, open it with some text editor like notepad++ and see in the down right corner the encoding value. Or ask the person who provided you the file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help.

Comment: Last night I worked with your code, and found that all spaces are replaced with '\xa0', and an empty result was produced.

Comment: @john Deer What is your encoding? Did you figure out which one to use?

Comment: My encoding was 'UTF8'. Last night I installed Notepad++ and checked it. All spaces through out the file was replaced with '\xa0' when `filePath.map(lambda x :x[1].decode('utf-8')).collect()` is run.

Comment: if your encoding is utf8 then you should not have any problem at first. Utf8 is the default encoding. If spaces are replaced it means your encoding is different.

Comment: But Notepad++ mentioned it as 'UTF8'. I have even tried saving a copy by converting it to 'UTF8' and work with it. But it did not work. I can even send you the file, if you wish so

Comment: @JohnDeer Can you try this : `print(sc.binaryFiles("/user/cloudera/Hin*/datafile.txt").take(1))`